# How do I manually configure a JdbcTemplate in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring

Here's my basic DAO implementation class:

```
@Repository
public class MeetingDaoImpl implements MeetingDao {

  @Autowired
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  public boolean insertNewMeeting(String initials, String meetingId, int numYears) {

    int numRowsAffected = jdbcTemplate.update(SQLConstants.INSERT_NEW_MEETING,
        new Object[] {initials.toLowerCase(), meetingId, numYears});

    return numRowsAffected > 0;

  }
}
```

The `jdbcTemplate` automatically reads the `spring.datasource` properties from my `application.properties` file, which is great, but it includes my DB password which is something I don't want to commit. Instead, I'd like to read it from a local `server.properties` file instead which I can easily read from a Java class.

Is there a way to configure the `jdbcTemplate` with Java? I've seen multiple examples using a bean and XML, but none with Java.

Comment: Then don't commit it... Instead of working around the framework, work with the framework. Either provide the password as a parameter when starting the application, or put in an `application.properties` next to the jar or set is as an environment variable. See the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) on how and where you can read properties from.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just declare a `JdbcTemplate` bean:

```
@Bean
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    // extract this 4 parameters using your own logic
    final String driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver";
    final String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:h2:mem:test";
    final String username = "sa";
    final String password = "";
    // Build dataSource manually:
    final Class<?> driverClass = ClassUtils.resolveClassName(driverClassName, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    final Driver driver = (Driver) ClassUtils.getConstructorIfAvailable(driverClass).newInstance();
    final DataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource(driver, jdbcUrl, username, password);
    // or using DataSourceBuilder:
    final DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().driverClassName(driverClassName).url(jdbcUrl).username(username).password(password).build();
    // and make the jdbcTemplate
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

Another way is not to setup datasource parameters in your `application.properties` file, but to declare it on runtime instead. When you're running your app you can override any properties defined within `application.properties` or define a new ones.

For example:

`java -jar my-spring-boot-app.jar --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test --spring.datasource.username=sa --spring.datasource.password=secret`

The more sophisticated way is to use [spring-cloud-config-server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html) or [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) for managing your settings.

Comment: I put that function in a new class, `DatabaseConfig`, but how do I implement it in my DAO?

Comment: In DAO just inject `JdbcTemplate` as before as it should work just like before

Comment: I had to add `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` to the main application class to prevent the auto-configuration of the JDBC template, but then it worked! Thanks!

Comment: What ClassUtils are you using? Eclipse gives me like 10 choices.

Comment: @mmaceachran the one from [spring-framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can give properties like below :

`datasource.local.url=
datasource.local.driver-class-name=
datasource.local.username=
datasource.local.password=`

Create a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
   @ConfigurationProperties("datasource.local")
   @EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com...",
        transactionManagerRef = "localTransactionManager",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "localEntityManagerFactory"
    )
    public class OracleConfiguration {
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private String url;

    private String driverClassName;


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource localDataSource() throws SQLException {

         return DataSourceBuilder
                 .create()
                 .url(this.url)
                 .username(this.username)
                 .password(this.password)
                 .driverClassName(this.driverClassName)
                 .build();
    }

    public String getDriverClassName() {
        return driverClassName;
    }

    public void setDriverClassName(String driverClassName) {
        this.driverClassName = driverClassName;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public PlatformTransactionManager localTransactionManager(@Qualifier("localEntityManagerFactory")
                                                                          EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("localDataSource")DataSource dataSource) {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com...");

        return factoryBean;
    }
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate localJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("localDataSource")DataSource dataSource) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }}
```

In your main application class, include this Configuration file:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ OracleConfiguration.class})
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }}
```

Then in your class where you need to inject the template:

```
@Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate localJdbcTemplate;
```

Comment: That seems like an awful lot of work just to configure a data source, there's not a more simple way?