# spring boot assign specific DataSource to JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two datasources that I'm trying to assign a specific datasource to each JpaRepositories. I'm using the spring boot framework. The primary datasource is used about 90% of the time while the secondary datasource is used about 10% so it would be nice to default to the primary and only assign the secondary datasource when required.  I tried using the docs here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html , but I dont think its exactly what I need.  Any tips would be great!

```
spring.datasource.configuration.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase
spring.datasource.configuration.username=dockerusername
spring.datasource.configuration.password=dockerpassword
spring.datasource.configuration.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource.cached.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:main
spring.datasource.cached.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver

spring.datasource.initialize=false
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

config file

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.praeses.gov"})
public class Config {
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.configuration")
public DataSourceProperties configDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.configuration")
public DataSource configDataSource() {
    return configDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.cached")
public DataSourceProperties cachedDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.cached")
public DataSource cachedDataSource() {
return cachedDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }
```

repository that uses the primary datasource

```
@Qualifier("spring.datasource.cached")
@Repository("spring.datasource.cached")
public interface GeoitemRepository extends JpaRepository<Geoitem, String> {
}
```

repository that uses the secondary datasource

```
@Qualifier("spring.datasource.configuration")
@Repository("spring.datasource.configuration")
public interface GeoitemhistoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Geoitemhistory, String> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something on similar lines as below link. Just create two config files instead of one(one each for each datasource) and add both of them to your main application.

Also, in the properties file, give as below:

```
datasource.local.url=
datasource.local.driver-class-name=
datasource.local.username=
datasource.local.password=

datasource.primary.url=
datasource.primary.driver-class-name=
datasource.primary.username=
datasource.primary.password=
```

Also, give `@Primary` annotation to the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and `platformTransactionManager` in the config file for primary datasource.

See this answer for more details: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44971911/6775742